# Ubuntu 14.04, Apache 2.4.7, Phpbrew and PHP7 renders PHP files only as plain text

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, php-7

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and need to run PHP7 locally alongside PHP5. I installed Phpbrew and all seems to have worked:

```
➜  ~ phpbrew list
* php-7.0.6      
  php-5.6.21
```

I did:

`sudo a2dismod php5`

`sudo a2enmod php7`

`sudo service apache2 restart`

But when I open the browser and move to my local Apache site, PHP files do not get rendered. **They are shown simply as plain text**.

When I switch to PHP 5.6.21 and enable php5 module all working as expected.

Any idea how I can solve this? I used Phpbrew so I can use PHP5 and PHP7 alongside on my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, solved by adding following line in /etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.load

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```